# Letter in mail about a foreclosed house I owned selling at auction and them trying to get the funds for me

Tags: united-states, foreclosure

...I'm sure as long as they get a cut.

I received a letter from multiple companies, so there must be some way for me to get this information and get the money that's owed to me, if any, and I'm sure the information is public. I just don't know where to start.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've had at least two of these letters mention about the same figure.

I'm located in west Pasco county, Florida.

More details as per comment below:

What's weird is that the sale that just occurred was $21K. I bought the house for $107K 3 months before the bubble popped nearly 10 years ago. I owed probably 85-90K on it. After the bubble popped it was probably worth $30K. When I bought it I didn't know what I was doing and the house had lots of problems, including the roof, so I abandoned it after 3 years. Because of my daughter's medical bills at the time, I filed for bankruptcy. That's why I found it strange that I was getting a refund. At first I thought it was some sort of joke considering the circumstances.

I'm in Florida, and fltreasurehunt.com came up with nothing.

Comment: Talk to the bank. If there is any money left over after they take what you owe them, your getting the remainder should be straightforward. I would be very suspicious of anyone contacting you, unsolicited, claiming to want to help you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you should be able to get your hands on any monies owing without the help of a third party.  This sounds similar to "Heir Hunters", professionals who hunt down heirs to estates and convince them to sign up to a contract entitling the heir hunter to a cut of the proceeds.  Most people are happy to receive an unexpected windfall and sign up, but there is no legal requirement to do so.  They are still entitled to the inheritance regardless. As Keshlam suggests (above), start by talking to the mortgage provider or possibly the auction house.

Comment: How would I find the bank? I checked my county's appraiser website for my old property but it didn't give me much info except the people (sounds like husband-and-wife LLC) who bought the property.

Comment: @DerreckDean Frankly speaking, you should already know. Banks don't suddenly "own" your home without some form of paper trail. Since the home was foreclosed, it sounds like you had taken out a mortgage against it at some point. As NickR stated, you would need to talk to the mortgage provider.

Comment: Ah, I was never thinking about contacting my lender. Great idea, I'm going to look that up thank you

Comment: It still does not answer the question of, how was these different companies able to find that information out in the first place? They must've been somewhere they were able to look

Comment: Where they might have got the information from would heavily depend on where you are located, so [edit] your question to indicate that, but a good start might be whatever government agency in your country registers (land) property ownership.

Comment: Question has been edited.

Comment: Public records. I can easily search for real estate transactions, and with a bit of detective work, see if the sale was higher than the lien/mortgage.

Comment: What's weird is that the sale that just occurred was $21K. I bought the house for $107K 3 months before the bubble popped nearly 10 years ago. I owed probably 85-90K on it. After the bubble popped it was probably worth $30K. When I bought it I didn't know what I was doing and the house had lots of problems, including the roof, so I abandoned it after 3 years. Because of my daughter's medical bills related to leukemia, I filed for bankruptcy. (She's fine now.) That's why I found it strange that I was getting a refund. At first I thought it was some sort of joke considering the circumstances.

Comment: Are they debt collectors trying to get you to claim a debt that wasn't cleared by the bankruptcy? I'd be very suspicious.

Comment: Since multiple companies are doing this I would check the state's unclaimed property listing.

Comment: fltreasurehunt.com came up with nothing.

Comment: LOL, got another postcard in the mail yesterday from a different company.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting a letter in the mail **a while later** from Florida Treasure Hunt, and I did end up getting something from it. This brings up a very interesting find: Florida Treasure Hunt must first sell the listings to third-party companies to see if they can get your business. That's the only explanation I have for what happened.

Comment: Or the bank sells the listings.  They may even do it as part of the process of listing on Florida Treasure Hunt.  One of the steps could be "Have you attempted to contact the person owed?"  Rather than the bank paying out investigation money they can't recoup, perhaps they trade the listing for the investigation.  If you don't sign within the time period, they hand off the listing to the government agency with your newly investigated contact details.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense,